# Can I send an iMessage via iCloud?

Tags: ios, messages

I logged into iCloud.com but there is no option to send an iMessage.

Is it possible to send an iMessage through iCloud or any other website?

Comment: I'm 98.735% sure this isn't possible but I'd love to be wrong.

Comment: There currently isnt, but I would like to see iMessage for the Mac, could happen as they did it with FaceTime

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**

For the moment Apple has been extremely quiet about how to access the protocol, and there has been no confirmed plans for iMessage to for the Mac. However, they will most likely release a version for every Apple platform.

I don't think however, they will create a web interface, since no one else has really come up with one that works well.

Answer (score -3):

Aha!
Look this website: http://www.imessageweb.com, it can send an imessage through webpage!

Comment: This seems not to work on UK phone numbers, so I suspect it's probably only to US phone numbers, and not to any form of registered imessage address (such as emails etc that can be registered as a valid recipient).  Also, because (thankfully) it does not request your login details in order to use your account and therefore make the you the sender, I imagine that it comes through as a generic sender unrecognised to the recipient.

Comment: That site looks like a way for people to add their mobile numbers to a marketing list as opposed to a site that has a reasonable chance of being legitimate for sending a secure iMessage. Even if I wanted to use a web to SMS gateway, the site linked here looks fishy to me. Worse, you are handing them the credentials to your Apple ID with iCloud backups, iCloud documents, and potentially payment information and purchasing power. Enabling two factor authentication or ensuring your challenge questions are unguessable are your only safety net if you give someone your password/ID.